# Compute Root Mean Squared Error and obtain a 3D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, math, sqrt

I have two 3d arrays A `A.shape=[335,71,57]` and B `B.shape=[335,71,57]` and I compute the RMSE between them in this way

```
rmse=sqrt(mean_squared_error(A,B))
```

and of course, I obtain a scalar. How could write it in order to obtain `rmse.shape=[335,71,57]` so another 3-dimensional array? In practice, I would need to obtain a `rmse` value for each position in the array.

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  The whole point of a "mean" error is that it is averaged over a number of samples.  You can't get an rmse for each position, the concept doesn't make sense.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example:

```
A = np.random.rand(10,10,10)
B = np.random.rand(10,10,10)
mse = ((A-B)**2)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
```

The third line will get you per element squared error, the last line will get per element root.

Note that what you are looking for is not the MSE, as the MSE is the mean of the squared error, and you are looking for per item.

By adding `mse = mse.mean(axis=ax)` you can get the mean, in an axis you choose (before taking the root).

For example:

```
A = np.random.rand(10,10,10)
B = np.random.rand(10,10,10)
mse = ((A-B)**2).mean(axis=0)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
```

Will take per row RMSE.

Comment: thank you. But if I use mse = mse.mean(axis=ax) I obtain 1 dimensional array and I need 2 dimension.

Comment: I think you are confusing the definition of mean squared error - in MSE you are taking the mean, e.g. not per item. I have added another block on how to take the RMSE of the per row mean. you can modify the axis to choose in which axis you want to take the mean.
If your expecting your `rmse` to have the same shape as `A`, thats not the rmse, but the root of (per item) squared error.

Comment: yes I edit the comment infact. but I need 2 dimensional array

Comment: Then see the last example I added, the result is 2d.

Comment: thank you!! so if I need to keep rmse value as a 3d array I don't put .mean(axis=0) correct?

Comment: yes, correct, just that would be the root squared error without the mean.

Comment: could you suggest me the same thing for the correlation coefficient? corr=np.corrcoef(A,B) by the result is 3d, how would you transform it in 2 dimensions? thankss